# Lebesgue measurability of binary numbers

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A:=\{x\in[0,1]\,|\,x=0.\,a_1a_2\ldots,\, (a_i\in\{0,1\}),\, \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\#\{a_k=1,\,1\leq k\leq n \}}{\#\{a_k=0,\,1\leq k\leq n \}}=1\}$.

$\#\{a_k=1,\,1\leq k\leq n\}$ is the number of 1's until the n-th digit in the binary representation of number $x$.

I have to prove that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I read some facts about Cantor set to find an idea what could be used in this situation, but I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify each sequence of binary decimals as an infinite sequence of coin tosses. Then you can identify for each binary sequence a unique number on the unit interval. the Lebesgue measure of a binary number is then just $\lambda([0,x])$